# Fill in a text file using R

Tags: string, r, text, stringr

I have a text file of the sort:

> "Hello,
>
> I have %d dogs and %d cats,
>
> which on average weight respectively %f and %f kilograms... "

I am trying to create an R function that takes as input a vector
(for instance `c(2, 3, 3.4, 2.3)`) and uses its entries to fill the %f and %d
in the text file (in the correct order).

This should be quite straightforward, but I can't find a proper way to
do it. Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for the `sprintf` function.

Comment: There's an R package called `brew` which is designed for filling in templates - different syntax to this but same outcomes. Just an FYI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can write your template using `brew` package syntax you can do this:

```
I have <%= ndogs %> dogs and <%= ncats %> cats which on
average weight <%= dogweight/ndogs %> and <%= catweight/ncats %> kg
respectively
```

then install `brew`, and do:

```
require(brew)
dogweight=23
catweight=12
ncats=4
ndogs=2
brew("animals.txt")
```

produces:

```
I have 2 dogs and 4 cats which on
average weight 11.5 and 3 kg
respectively
```

which you can send to another file or capture as text into R.

You can also do loops in the template. There's no 8192 character limit like `sprintf`.

Answer (score 3):

As @MatthewPlourde pointed out, the `sprintf` function should be useful here.

```
a<-"Hello,
I have %d dogs and %d cats,
which on average weight respectively %f and %f kilograms... "

sprintf(a, 2, 3, 3.4, 2.3)
```

This does require "unpacking" your vector as parameters. If you do have the values in a vector, you can do

```
v<-c(2, 3, 3.4, 2.3)
do.call(sprintf, c(list(a), v))
```

Comment: Thanks! One issue though: if I have a file "tmp.text", in order to use sprintf() should I load it all as a single character string? Because I tried to do that and I get an error from sprintf() because my text is larger than 8192 bytes. On the other hand if I use readLines, I get a vector where each line is a different entry, so using sprintf is not as straightforward as in the above example...