# Write each row of a dataframe as a text chunk and format all chunks in a text file with R

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting

I have a dataframe of experiment materials and would like to format it into an appendix text file. Each row in the dataframe represents one experiment item. Each column contains one aspect of the item. The dataframe looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Item = 1, Title = "Title of the pss", Passage = " Content of the passage", Question = "Is this statement correct?", Answer =  "Yes", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
item2 <- c(2, "Title 2", "Passage 2", "Question 2", "No")
df <- rbind(df, item2)
df

>
  Item            Title                 Passage                   Question   Answer
1    1 Title of the pss  Content of the passage Is this statement correct?      Yes
2    2          Title 2               Passage 2                 Question 2 Answer 2
```

I would like to write this dataframe into a text file in the following format:

```
Title: Title of the pss

Passage: 
Content of the passage

Question: 
Is this statement correct?

Answer: 
Yes


Title: Title 2

Passage: 
Passage 2

Question: 
Question 2

Answer: 
Answer 2
```

I would like to know

1. How to write each row as a text chunk?
2. How to format the text with R code?

I figured out how to do this with python in a roundabout way, but still like to know whether there is neat way to do it in R.

Many many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sprintf` function in base R (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24413342/9737325) for more info). This allows you to define a template string and then substitute values in. See below for an example, from this you could just iterate through rows of the dataframe to get the full output you need.

```
template <- "Title: %s

Passage: 
%s

Question: 
%s

Answer: 
%s"

df <- data.frame(Item = 1, Title = "Title of the pss", Passage = " Content of the passage", Question = "Is this statement correct?", Answer =  "Yes", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
item2 <- c(2, "Title 2", "Passage 2", "Question 2", "No")
df <- rbind(df, item2)
df

cat(sprintf(template, df[1, "Title"], df[1, "Passage"], df[1, "Question"], df[1, "Answer"]))
```

This gives the output

```
Title: Title of the pss

Passage: 
 Content of the passage

Question: 
Is this statement correct?

Answer: 
Yes
```

Edit: To go further you could wrap the `sprintf` in a function that returns a list and then print that list like so:

```
chunk_fun <- function(df) {
    text = c()
    for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
        text <- c(text, sprintf(template, df[i, "Title"], df[i, "Passage"], df[i, "Question"], df[i, "Answer"]))
    }
    return(text)
}
textx = chunk_fun(df)
cat(textx)
```

Output:

```
Title: Title of the pss

Passage:
Content of the passage

Question:
Is this statement correct?

Answer: 
Yes 
Title: Title 2

Passage:
Passage 2

Question:
Question 2

Answer: 
No
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Convert to dcf format, add appropriate newlines and write it out.

```
library(magrittr)
fileout <- stdout() # replace with your file name

df %>%
  .[-1] %>%
  write.dcf(stdout()) %>%
  capture.output %>%
  sub("^(Passage|Question|Answer): (.*)", "\n\\1:\n\\2", .) %>%
  sub("^Title", "\nTitle", .) %>%
  writeLines(fileout)
```

giving:

```
Title: Title of the pss

Passage:
Content of the passage

Question:
Is this statement correct?

Answer:
Yes


Title: Title 2

Passage:
Passage 2

Question:
Question 2

Answer:
No
```

**2)** If you are open to using dcf format instead then it is just one line and also has the benefit that `read.dcf` can read it back in.

```
write.dcf(df[-1], fileout)   # fileout is from above
```

giving:

```
Title: Title of the pss
Passage: Content of the passage
Question: Is this statement correct?
Answer: Yes

Title: Title 2
Passage: Passage 2
Question: Question 2
Answer: No
```